# Python Function Reuse

Tags: python, function

I have a function defined as below in my python code:

```
def insert_source():
    sql = "INSERT INTO public.source (width, height, sha1) " \
          "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    conn = None
    data = widtho, heighto, sha1o
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the INSERT statement
        cur.execute(sql, data)
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        print('Source image data successfully imported', sha1o)
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        if str(error) in "duplicate key value violates unique constraint":
            raise
        else:
            print("I've seen this image before, skipping insert")
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            return id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert_source()
```

this works fine and inserts that or throws an exception as expected. BUT now later in my script I want to write some more data in a different table within the same db. Should I copy/paste the entire function above and rename it or is there a better way to say do most of these things but the sql and data should be X?

FWIW duplicating that function results in a `Duplicated code fragment (31 lines long)` note so it just seems silly to replicate 98% of that code when I need to change 4 lines in total.

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph already answer your question?

Comment: This function is doing a *lot*.  It reads DB config from somewhere, establishes a DB connection, inserts new data, prints to the console, and handles errors.  I would start by refactoring this into smaller pieces.

Comment: yes but the HOW is key

Comment: By using a parameter for the 4 lines that need to change.

Comment: Consider changing your function so it takes in the sql and data as parameters, e.g., `def insert_source(sql, data):`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add arguments to the function for example table_name, things_to_insert, and values.. so your function will be like:

```py
def insert_source(table_name, things_to_insert, values):
    sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} {things_to_insert} VALUES {values}"
    conn = None
    data = widtho, heighto, sha1o
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the INSERT statement
        cur.execute(sql, data)
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        print('Source image data successfully imported', sha1o)
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        if str(error) in "duplicate key value violates unique constraint":
            raise
        else:
            print("I've seen this image before, skipping insert")
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            return id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_name = 'public.source'
    thing_to_insert = (width, height, sha1)
    values = '(%s, %s, %s)'
    insert_source(table_name, things_to_insert, values)
```

this will do exactly what your code does, and you can customize arguments to make the function reusable.

BUT, as Ted Klein Bergman said in the comments, this way is great candidate for SQL injections.
so what you have to do is to make prepared/parametrized queries as Klein suggested.

Comment: No, don't do this! This is a perfect candidate for SQL-injections! Never use string interpolation for SQL-queries! Instead, use prepared/parametrized queries.

Comment: @Tony Your question is about design and is thus highly dependent on your actual use-case, surrounding design and requirements. Most answers will be subjective or recommendations based on design paradigms. What's objective is that raw string interpolation is a candidate for SQL-injections and one of the most common and most devastating cyber-attacks out there.

Comment: @Tony The comment by [Justin Ezequiel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835435/python-function-reuse#comment116402144_65835435) seems more reasonable in that case.

Comment: still would like to see a working example of the params etc

Comment: Does this answer conform or no? Not sure why it’s upvoted if not